# sql server error msg 116, how to bypass

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with a subquery in my query.
In this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Statistic_RecordedConversations A
  JOIN (SELECT DID, max(DateTime) MaDate
        FROM Statistic_RecordedConversations
        where DID IN (
           Select OpenData as DID, QuestionID, InterviewID 
           from Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Data 
           where QuestionID = 895 
           and InterviewID in ( 
                select Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Data.InterviewID 
                from Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Interview, 
                     Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Data 
                where Surveys.dbo.askia2363Interview.InterviewID = 
                Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Data.InterviewID  
                and completed = 1 
                and QuestionID = 891 
                and ClosedData = 4685 
                and CAST(EndInterview as Date) = 
                CAST (Current_TIMESTAMP as Date)))
        GROUP BY DID ) B
      ON A.DID = B.DID
     AND A.DateTime = B.MaDate
```

I got an error with msg 116. I think its due to the ligne 6 where I have not only 1 column. I don't know how to get this query working. I tried EXISTS insteand of IN but got too many results and not the results that are interesting to me.

If someone got another solution, many thanks! :)

Comment: Your query makes no sense and neither does your explanation. If you can explanation what you're after in with a data sample, that's a start

Comment: And always when you get an error, include the whole message. At least I can't remember what is error 116.

Comment: You should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Also, avoid using select *, select only the columns you need. Last but not least use aliases consistently and avoid aliases like a, b, c. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Ok I'll look for that. Sorry for the bad explaination. I'm gonna look at what you said. Thanks. The whole message is :Msg 116, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 4
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: To be honest I would consider rewriting this whole thing. Subqueries nested to multiple levels is a huge red flag that something has gone wrong.

Comment: The error description is very clear.  What else can we do to explain it to you????

Answer (score 3):

You can only return one field to correlate inside of an IN statement. You need to only return DID.

```
where DID IN ( Select OpenData as DID from Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Data...
```

Comment: Also you should fix your join syntax,  from Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Interview a join 
                     Surveys.dbo.Askia2363Data b  and add the join criteria; on a.id = b.id

Comment: Thanks, english isn't my first language so sorry for the explaination. Gonna try that. I'm not that good with SQL so many thanks =)